# How to set the outer border of two layers of text through CSS?

Tags: html, css

I came across a project that needed to use CSS to design such a font!
But I really can’t implement it. How can I make a font with a white border outside the text and black text outside the white border. Here I would like to ask if anyone who has designed similar fonts can give me some help? Thank you all for your help

```css
body{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.demo{
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">9999</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some filter can approximate this:

```css
body{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.demo{
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px 0;
  margin:0;
  font-family:monospace;
  filter:
    /* white shadow */
    drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #fff) 
    /* then black shadow */
    drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #000) drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #000) drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px #000) 
    /* some contrast to limit the blur effect*/
    contrast(8)
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">9999</p>
```